# reindex catalog_category_product issues after migration from M1 to M2

Tags: magento2, indexing

After migration from M1 to M2 we get the following error when we run the following command

```
bin/magento index:reindex catalog_category_product
```

How can we solve these issues?

> .........58486', '58487', '58488', '58489', '58490', '58491', '58492',
>   '58493', '58494', '58495', '58496', '58497',
>   '58498', '58499', '58500', '58501', '58502', '58503', '58504',
>   '58505', '58506', '58507', '58508', '58509', '58510', '58511',
>   '58512', '58513', '58514', '585                     16', '58517',
>   '58518', '58519', '58520', '58521', '58522', '58523', '58524',
>   '58525', '58526', '58527', '58528', '58529', '58530', '58531',
>   '58532', '58533',                      '58534', '58535', '58536',
>   '58537', '58539', '58540', '58541', '58542', '58543', '58544',
>   '58545', '58546', '58547', '58548', '58549', '58550', '58551', '5855
>   2', '58553', '58554', '58555', '58556', '58557', '58558', '58559',
>   '58560', '58561', '58562', '58563', '58565', '58566', '58567',
>   '58568')) GROUP BY `cp`.`ent                     ity_id` ON DUPLICATE
>   KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` =
>   VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` =
>   VAL                     UES(`is_parent`), `store_id` =
>   VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)

Comment: Please share the full error

Answer (score 0):

> So far my understanding,You have some products ids at
>   `catalog_category_product` or `catalog_category_product_index`,
>   `catalog_category_product_index_replica`  and these tables Magento
>   save categories and products relation.

### 1. Issue not existing Product at category and products relation table

which has some **product ids** does not exist at `catalog_product_entity` but does not exist at those categories and products relation tables. So you have to remove/delete the product from `categories and products relation` table.

**You need to  run below:**

> delete from catalog_category_product where product_id not in (select
>   entity_id from catalog_product_entity)

### 2. Issue Duplicate Index key:

Magento has created **an index key** combine of `CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID_PRODUCT_ID`  on `catalog_category_product` table which has some duplicate record.

catalog_category_product_index has **an database index key** `CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY`  combine of  field `product_id,store_id,category_id,visibility`, You have to find out those record and remove from respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check .log, may you have innodb_buffer_pool_size problem, you can fix this by server settings.